# How to Input 2 Variables of Different Type into a List<T>

Tags: c#, list

I would like to store 2 variables of different types, of which one is a `class`, and the next is a `Guid`.

May I know if it can be done using List?

```
Desired output: 

List<myClass> = new List<myClass>();

myClass.add(class1, "01-0001");
```

Comment: How about a Dictionary<string,MyClass>

Comment: Are those the only two things you are going to store in the collection? Why do you want to do this? Different reasons may yield different solutions

Comment: By the way, GUIDs have 128-bits (generally rendered as 32 hex digits with some punctuation). What you are showing is a string

Comment: Please use proper naming conventions. Class names need to start with capitalized letters and fields and variables with lowercase. `class MyClass { int myField; }`

Comment: Do also consider a strongly-typed tuple: `var list = new List<(MyClass MyClass, string Guid)>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just use a `Tuple<myclass, string>` as your type for the list generic parameter:

```
List<Tuple<myclass, string>> list = new List<Tuple<myclass, string>>();
list.Add(Tuple.Create(class1, "01-0001"));
```